# Keeping track of answers within a program without knowing how many questions will be answered

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, loops, computer-science

I have been trying to figure out how to display something like "You answered 7 out of 8 problems correctly. Your score is 95.5% with a grade of A." in my program. I have written most of it, but now have spent some time searching the internet for a way. I'm not familiar with arrays.

My program is a fraction calculator that is supposed to calculate the basic operations (+,-,*,division) and is supposed to exit when I enter % as my sentinel value.

This is what I have written so far. Any feedback is highly appreciated. How would I go about keeping track of something as the number of questions answered correctly without knowing how many times the user will repeat the process (program)? This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

enum MenuSelection {
    NONE=0,
    ADD=1,
    SUBTRACT=2,
    MULTIPLY=3,
    DIVIDE=4,
    QUIT=5,
    END=6,
};

int menu() {
    int MenuSelection=0;
    do {
        cout<<"\n1) Add"<<endl;
        cout<<"2) Subtract"<<endl;
        cout<<"3) Multiply"<<endl;
        cout<<"4) Divide"<<endl;
        cout<<"5) %"<<endl;
        cin>>MenuSelection;
        //
        if (MenuSelection<=NONE||MenuSelection>=END)
            cout<<"Please pick a number from 1-5 as shown in the menu selection."<<endl;
        if (MenuSelection==QUIT) {
            cout<<"You have chosen to exit the program"<<endl;
            cout<<"You have answered \n";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    while (MenuSelection<=NONE||MenuSelection>=END);
    //
    return MenuSelection;
}

void addFractions(int num1, int num2, int den1, int den2, int &NUM_result, int &DEN_result) {        //
    NUM_result=(num1* den2)+(num2*den1);
    //
    DEN_result=den1*den2;
}

void subFractions(int num1, int num2, int den1, int den2, int &NUM_result, int &DEN_result) {
    NUM_result=(num1*den2)-(num2*den1);
    //
    DEN_result=den1*den2;
    //
}

void multiplyFractions(int num1, int num2, int den1, int den2, int &NUM_result, int &DEN_result) {
    NUM_result=num1*num2;
    //
    DEN_result=den1* den2;
}

void divideFractions(int num1, int num2, int den1, int den2, int &NUM_result, int &DEN_result) {            //
    NUM_result=num1*den2;
    //
    DEN_result=den1*num2;
}

void input_values_FROM_USER(int &num1, int &num2, int &den1, int &den2)
{
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the numerator for first fraction-->";
    cin>>num1;
    cout<<"Enter denominator for first fraction--> ";
    cin>>den1;
    cout<<"Enter numerator for second fraction--> ";
    cin>>num2;
    cout<<"Enter denominator for second fraction--> ";
    cin>>den2;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------\n\n\n";
}

void outputResults(int num1, int num2, int den1, int den2, int &NUM_result, int &DEN_result, int operation) {
    if (operation==ADD) {
        cout<<"The sum of the two is--> "<<num1<<'/'<<den1<<'+'<<num2<<'/'<<den2<<'='<<NUM_result<<'/'<<DEN_result<<endl;
    }
    if (operation==SUBTRACT) {
        cout<<"The difference of the two is--> "<<num1<<'/'<<den1<<'-'<<num2<<'/'<<den2<<'='<<NUM_result<<'/'<<DEN_result<<endl;
    }
    if (operation==MULTIPLY) {
        cout<<"The product of the two is--> "<<num1<<'/'<<den1<<'*'<<num2<<'/'<<den2<<'='<<NUM_result<<'/'<<DEN_result<<endl;
    }
    if (operation==DIVIDE) {
        cout<<"The quotient of the two is--> "<<num1<<'/'<<den1<<'/'<<num2<<'/'<<den2<<'='<<NUM_result<<'/'<<DEN_result<<endl;
    }
}

void main() {
    int MenuSelection=NONE;
    int num1=0, num2=0, den1=0, den2=0;
    int NUM_result=0, DEN_result=0;
    cout<<"Author: Jose Soto."<<endl;
    cout<<"CSCI 110-- Jose Soto's Project 2 (Basic Fraction Arithmetic)\n\n"<<endl;
    do {
        MenuSelection=menu();
        input_values_FROM_USER(num1, num2, den1, den2);
        if (MenuSelection==ADD)
        {
            addFractions(num1, num2, den1, den2, NUM_result, DEN_result);
        }
        if (MenuSelection==SUBTRACT) {
            subFractions(num1, num2, den1, den2, NUM_result, DEN_result);
        }
        if (MenuSelection==MULTIPLY) {
            multiplyFractions(num1, num2, den1, den2, NUM_result, DEN_result);
        }
        if (MenuSelection==DIVIDE) {
            divideFractions(num1, num2, den1, den2, NUM_result, DEN_result);
        }
        outputResults(num1, num2, den1, den2, NUM_result, DEN_result, MenuSelection);
    }
    while (MenuSelection!=QUIT);
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: You have very lengthy program because of unnecessary `\n`s

Comment: I think your question better suits to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A variable which is incremented each time a question is asked, and a second one which is incremented each time a question is answered correctly, seem to be in order. Then you can use them both in a calculation which doesn't result in 7 out of 8 being called 95.5%.